# Configuring response timeout in Apache JMeter

Tags: timeout, jmeter, httpresponse, load-testing, performance-testing

I am trying to check if a particular HTTP request's response time is over 30 seconds, and if it is, then mark it as failed and stop the thread. Sometimes I can see response times close to 80 seconds, an no browser is waiting that long for a response from the server.

I found the following three ways to set a timeout value in JMeter, however this confuses me, because there is multiple options and I don't know which one to use, or if there is any difference at all between them.

So here are the options I found that are related to response timeout:

1. Setting Response timeout value in the sampler
   [image: Method 1]
2. Add a Duration assertion

[image: Method 2]
3. Setting timeout in *jmeter.properties* configuration file. Options I found here:

1. *os_sampler.poll_for_timeout=x*
2. *http.socket.timeout=x*
3. *httpclient.timeout=x*

So, the problem is that I don't know where to set the response timeout from the listed options. Is there any difference at all between these options?
**So what I would like to see as a result: If a particular HTTP request takes more than 30 seconds to get a response from the server, stop waiting for a response and mark it as a failed request.**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For your need, an assertion is not the right solution as it will only mark the request as failed but it will wait.

The right option is a response timeout.

Regarding the 3rd point

1. os_sampler.poll_for_timeout=x => not for http, see:

   - https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/bin/jmeter.properties
2. http.socket.timeout=x =>  applies to all requests using HttpClient4 or 3, see:

   - https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/bin/hc.parameters
3. httpclient.timeout=x => Same, see:

   - https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/bin/jmeter.properties

I think the best option is to use 1. , if you want those values to apply to all requests, just use Http Request Defaults element:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults

[image: HTTP Request Defaults]

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: So... does Http Request Defaults element override underlying `http.socket.timeout` and `httpclient.timeout` - I would assume so?

Answer (score 34):

Socket/Connect and Read/Response timeouts can be set from `Http Request Defaults` section at jmeter GUI. See sample:

Connect timeout: 3 seconds
Response timeout: 20 seconds.

[image]