# JMeter stuck at 'Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445'

Tags: linux, testing, jmeter

I am trying to use jmeter on the command line using:

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t testplan.jmx -l log.jtl
```

It works 8/10 times but some times it gets stuck on the message: `waiting for possible shutdown message..`. I am using CentOS 6 and JMeter version 2.9 r1437961. My test plan has two thread groups which are configured to run consecutively from the GUI. Any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you looked in Jmeter logs? The answer can be there.

Comment: Adding to that, JMeter doesn't necessarily output anything after the `waiting for possibleshutdown message...`. It usually only outputs once every 30-60 seconds or so.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue? I'm having the same problem in Linux only. It's all good in windows

Comment: It's just bad UX design.  By the time you notice the message, the indicated "waiting" phase has most likely already completed (unfortunately, with no immediate indication).  If nothing else is being displayed, it is probably stuck on something it hasn't bothered to tell you about.  I would recommend running without `-n` (to use the GUI mode), but that doesn't seem to be any more informative (as of version 4.0).  As noted in the answers, the problem is most likely a failed connection within your tests and, if so, adding timeouts will likely make that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set timeouts to your HTTP requests ?
If not , then jmeter will wait infinitely for a response from server which can lead to such issue.

So fix is to set a timeout on connect and read in HTTP Request Defaults.

Also you shoud upgrade to JMeter 2.13.

Comment: I am facing similar issue with junit sampler. How to set timeout for junit sampler ?

Answer (score 0):

To further breakdown UBIK LOAD PACK's comments,

- Navigate to Testplan level and Add--> config Element --> HTTP Request
  Defaults.
- Set the protocol, server Name and port (Not sure if you really need
  it, but worked for me)
- Navigate to advanced tab and add timeout periods(milliseconds) to
  Connect and response timeouts( I set as 10000)

Comment: More here: [Configuring response timeout in Apache JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25207879/86967)

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this error when I mistakenly disabled my Test Suite in JMeter UI.
I kept on running the jmeter command in terminal and was getting this error. Re-enabling it fixed the error. It was a dumb mistake but worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are passing quotes when providing the jmx file location. Example : -n -t "testplan.jmx". If so, remove and try. -n -t testplan.jmx