# How to check the acessibility of a page using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Have to check the accessibility of one API. If it has not opened within any stipulated time and then send email to stakeholders. When I am using "Duration Assertion" to check the time duration, than JMeter will access the page first calculate the time than compare with the given time and do the action.

But the problem is to check the accessibility. So when it is not accessible or down than the meter is waiting for it irrespective of the time limit.

So how to kill the process and send the email if the API is not accessible or down.

Comment: Try using connection timeout or other timeouts mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207879/configuring-response-timeout-in-apache-jmeter

Comment: or use curl/wget if possible. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout/94612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set :

- Connect timeout
- Response timeout

As per this screenshot :

[image]