# If Loadtime in HTTP request is longer than 10000, what's throws an exception automatically?

Tags: jmeter

If Loadtime in HTTP request is longer than 10000 ms, what's throws an exception automatically? using JMeter.

> Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
>   Response message: Non HTTP response message:  failed to respond

But all requests are executed correctly in the application, only, their responses are above 10000 ms.

I modify the "Timeouts" into the HTTP request sampler.

Actually I test with 3.0 version, but also I've tested with 2.13 version

Could I do disable this automate check? Or modify the threshold with a major value (i.e: 500000)?

Comment: Maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207879/configuring-response-timeout-in-apache-jmeter

Comment: I see that using "HTTP Request Default" and the "response timeout" is minor than 10000 (i.e: 3000), this exception is throws perfectly in the value expected, but if this value is 15000, the exception is throws in 10000.

Some config where this value (10000) is configured?

Comment: I modified these values to 50000 and continue throws the exception with a loadtime of 10000 ms:


**hc.parameters:http.socket.timeout$Integer=50000
hc.parameters:http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
httpclient.parameters:http.socket.timeout$Integer=50000

jmeter.properties:hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters**