# Jmeter Default Time Out Setting in Property Fiels

Tags: jmeter, property-files

Will JMeter go to Sleep mode if JMeter did not Respond for 5 Min for Any Sample, Is there any setting in properties files to change This time OUT

as i am not getting response for a request with single user and JMeter is Getting hanged or Going to Sleep mode after 300 Sec

Updated below to 900 Sec in Properties File

/*Timeout in milliseconds for Report generation when using Tools > Generate HTML report
generate_report_ui.generation_timeout=300000

Updated below to 9000 m Sec in Properties File

Check connections if the elapsed time (Milliseconds) since the last
use of the connection exceed this value
httpclient4.validate_after_inactivity=4900*/

Comment: [Try this SO Answer it might help] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207879/configuring-response-timeout-in-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Tried this Scenarios, we are getting below socket exception 

/*java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.endRead(NioSocketImpl.java:253)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:332)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355)
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808)
 at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
 at 
*/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to set timeout for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers - the settings live under "Advanced" tab:

[image]

If you have more than one HTTP Request sampler in your test plan - it's better to use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/the-jmeter-pros-load-testing-checklist/23665)

In case you use some custom Samplers or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which don't have their own timeout mechanisms you can go for [Sample Timeout](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Timeout) Pre-Processor

Comment: Sorry, if i had conveyed my issue incorrectly

Comment: Sorry, if i had conveyed my issue incorrectly

Issue : I had a HTTP Request and its response time is 8 MIN, when i ran on UI i am getting proper response on UI, But when i try to execute the JMX Script JMeter is Not Providing any response

When i run the same Script with Request ID which Response time is around 5 min it is working fine

i had Tried with many Request ID's if we got the Response before 5 min its displaying, if NOT Jmeter is going to kind of Sleep Mode

So i am asking like is there any default time out in property files of JMeter which makes JMeter to Behave such a way